# SQL alter table query stuck in execute

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, alter-table

I'm trying to run an alter table query to add columns to an existing table:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Names
Add solCorporate bit null
```

When I execute it just sticks in the executing query cycle, I've left it for 20 mins and nothing.

Any ideas? I'm presuming if there was a code error it would flag before running.

Thanks.

Comment: is the table really big? have you tried running it multiple times?

Comment: How many rows in `dbo.Names`?

Comment: Table in use (DB lock)?

Comment: If your table is huge then If you have a Scratch DB make a copy of names and empty it out. Then try adding it and see if it gets stuck. Just to better troubleshoot the problem. Also please use (NOLOCK)

Comment: Take a look at it in SQL Server Profiler

Comment: There are aorund 25,000 records in the table. I've tried running it several times and the same thing happens.

No-one else is using the table at the moment.

Comment: Before running your query, run `select @@spid` to get the ID of your connection.  While your query is running, in another connection, run `EXEC sp_who` and look at the `blk` column to see if any connections are being blocked.  If there are blocked connections, look at the `spid` column to see if yours is being blocked.  Some other connection may have an open transaction that they did not close, or something to that effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem today. I tried to stop the database connection by right-clicking it and choosing Stop (in the Object Explorer in MS SQL Server Management Studio).

When that didn't help I launched Sql Server Configuration Manager and restarted the SQL Server from the SQL Server Services tab. After that, Alter table ran in a second.

Answer (score 0):

Closing SQL server management studio worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me while I was using the view in SSIS. Once I closed the SSIS project in Visual Studio, the execution finished immediately.

It is possible another program is hogging access to the view.